# .NET Core - targets on Debug arguments

Tags: .net-core

I have the following setup in a NET461 template project in the csproj

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
   <StartAction>Program</StartAction>
   <StartProgram>C:\ProgramData\XXX\XXX.exe</StartProgram>
   <StartArguments>"$(TargetPath)"</StartArguments>
   <StartWorkingDirectory>$(TargetDir)</StartWorkingDirectory>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I am now trying to migrate to .NET CORE, and I cannot get these properties to fill (they are just ignored and the created project has the target names left in there)

They are defined within launchSettings.json (by default when I use VS properties to set them)

```
{
 "profiles": {
   "Template": {
     "commandName": "Executable",
     "executablePath": "C:\\ProgramData\\XXX\\XXX.exe",
     "commandLineArgs": "$(OutDir)",
     "workingDirectory": "$(ProjectDir)"
   }
 }
```

}

I also have the csproj importing the Microsfot SDK (which should import all default targets from what I understand)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

Testing with post build events works fine when building, and the expected output is correct e.g.

```
echo $(OutDir)
```

I have also tried to add StartArguments to a Property Group within the csproj file, and it is ignored completely

I just can't seem to get these targets working for Debug Application Arguments.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So finally figured out that the Build Targets are not rendered in VS UI on build like they used to... so you won't actually "see" the result in the project, just the target param e.g. $(TargetPath).

This makes it seem like they are being completely ignored and just entered as plain text, however these actually are sent across correctly... so the above actually does work